# To find the mean of entire row

Tags: r

Need to know the meaning of each and every command . This is used to find the mean of entire row. But it also contains character type. So this code is used.

`rowMeans(sapply(iris, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), na.rm = T)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create an index to check the column type and then apply the `rowMeans` on the `numeric` columns

```
i1 <- sapply(iris, is.numeric)
rowMeans(iris[i1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: may i know why na.rm is used

Comment: @user14978544 it is just in case there are missing values (`NA`) in the dataset.  With `iris`, there is no need, but I used in case for a general case

Comment: write a program to input any value and check whether it is character, numeric or special character. How to write code for this question using nested if else loop.

Comment: @PreethiReddy You can check the `class` with `f1 <- function(x) class(x); f1(5); f1('a')` if it is a data.frame `sapply(df1, class)`

Comment: how to write it using nested if else loop . may I know why function(x) is used .

Comment: @PreethiReddy the `f1` is a function which can be applied to multiple objects.  Regarding the nested if else, your question is not clear to me

Comment: inside f1 you wrote function(x) right? i want to know why it is used.

Comment: I guess you need `f2 <- function(x) class(type.convert(x, as.is = TRUE))` then call it as `f2(my.name); f2(my.age)`